# Big-Theta functions for also with running time in log(n!) and log(n)+log(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

*log(n!) = log(n*n(-1)*....1) = log(n)+log(n-1)+....+log(1)*.  So it is in *O(n*logn)*. But is it also in *big-Omega(n*logn)*?  I don't think so, but my automated interview test thought so!

*log(n)+log(n^2) =  log(n)+2*log(n) = 3*log(n)*. So, it is in, big-O, big-Omega and big-Theta(log(n)).  But for some reason my automated interview test thought otherwise.

Is my understanding correct or is the automated test correct?

P.S:  I hate automated interview tests!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming (try http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 1):

> log(n)+log(n^2) = log(n)+2*log(n) = 3*log(n). So, it is in, big-O,
>   big-Omega and big-Theta(log(n)). But for some reason my automated
>   interview test thought otherwise.

IMO, you are correct, and the automatic interview test is not (if you presented the question correctly).

> log(n!) = log(n*n(-1)*....1) = log(n)+log(n-1)+....+log(1). So it is
>   in O(n*logn). But is it also in big-Omega(n*logn)? I don't think so,
>   but my automated interview test thought so!

The automatic interview test is correct, and you are not. log(n!) = log(n)+log(n-1)+....+log(1) >= log(n)+...+log(n/2) = (n/2) log(n/2) >= (n/2) log(sqrt(n)) = n*log(n)/4  (all ">=" are for sufficiently large n)

Answer (score 1):

About log n! and big-Omega:

n! multiplies the numbers from 1 to n. The second half of those numbers are all ≥ n / 2 ≥ sqrt (n), so log n! ≥ (n/2) * log (sqrt (n))) = n/2 * log (n) / 2 = (n log n) / 4. That lower bound is awfully bad, but good enough to show easily that log n! = big Omega (n log n).

Comment: It may have been easier (and more accurate) to point him to Stirling's approximation.